# Angular service wait for Observable in constructor

Tags: angular, observable

I have an Angular 2 service with this constructor:

```
constructor(public fireAuth: AngularFireAuth)
{
    console.log('1');
    fireAuth.authState.subscribe(user =>
    {
        console.log('2');
        this.user = user;
    });
    console.log('3');
}
```

When it's instantiated, the log order is 1, 3 and 2, because the 2nd log is inside the Observable. I can't use it `async/await` because it's in the service `constructor`. Is there any way to make this call synchronous?

Comment: I think the better question is why are you trying to do this in your service constructor?

Comment: read the documention, it depends on whether the fireBase supports synchrounous calls

Comment: Sync XHR are huge no-no. You can't. You shouldn't. The solution is in the question. If you can't do this in constructor, you shouldn't do this in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the complete callback;

```
console.log('1');
fireAuth.authState.subscribe(
  user => {
      console.log('2');
      this.user = user;
  },
  error => console.error(error),
  () => {
      console.log('3');
  });
```